# googleapi/drive in node.js

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to integrate [googleapi/drive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googleapis/drive) using Node.js and also I need to integrate the API in React.js.

What issue I am facing into is that I am getting a couple of weird error messages in the front-end.

I have the following codes in Node.js.

```
      import { auth, drive } from "@googleapis/drive"
      ...
      const driveAuth = new auth.GoogleAuth({
        keyFilename: path.join(__dirname, '../oauth2.keys.json'),
        scopes: [
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
        ],
      })
      const authClient = await driveAuth.getClient()

      const driveService = await drive({
        auth: authClient,
      }).files.list()
```

If I integrate this API in the front-end, then I get a error message.

```
message: "Unable to load endpoint drive(\"undefined\"): ctr is not a constructor"
```

If I check the console log for the `GoogleAuth`, then I get the following.

```
JWT {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  transporter: DefaultTransporter {},
  credentials: { refresh_token: 'jwt-placeholder', expiry_date: 1 },
  eagerRefreshThresholdMillis: 300000,
  forceRefreshOnFailure: false,
  certificateCache: {},
  certificateExpiry: null,
  certificateCacheFormat: 'PEM',
  refreshTokenPromises: Map(0) {},
  _clientId: undefined,
  _clientSecret: undefined,
  redirectUri: undefined,
  email: undefined,
  keyFile: 'E:\\work\\backend\\oauth2.keys.json',
  key: undefined,
  keyId: undefined,
  scopes: undefined,
  subject: undefined,
  additionalClaims: undefined,
  defaultServicePath: undefined,
  useJWTAccessWithScope: undefined,
  defaultScopes: undefined,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

My final goal is to create a folder in the google drive.

I already enabled google drive api in my console, and created a credential using OAuth2 Client ID.

What's wrong? I guess my GoogleAuth is failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the version of the api you want to use in the service

```
// Create a service account initialize with the service account key file and scope needed
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: KEYFILEPATH,
    scopes: SCOPES
});
const driveService = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
```

Code ripped from [Upload Image to Google drive with Node Js](https://www.daimto.com/upload-image-to-google-drive-with-node-js/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Btw, I just set the version as v3 and now I am getting `key must be a string, a buffer or an object`. Should I read the lines from the json file one by one? It is a bit annoying.

Comment: did you update KEYFILEPATH to be your key file since you didnt create a constant like i have?

Comment: It's real path. If I set a wrong path, then it fails.

Comment: You mean I should use an env variable for it?

Comment: Seems like I should use service account json file rather than auth client json. Thanks.